# Add functionality to first button in list only

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML (stripped down)

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <button type="button">Remove</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <button type="button">Remove</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript

```
$('body').on('click', 'li > button', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();

  if($('li > button').length === 1) { // if this is the only button
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); // remove whole list
    // remove some other elements outside the list      
  }

  if($(this).parent().is(':first')) { // if this first li in ul 
    if (confirm("...")) {
      $(this).parent().remove();    
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

- Make first button to remove the parent list item
- If the button is the only one in the `<ul>` remove the whole list and another element

How can I correctly make this work?

Comment: And if it is not the first button what have to do ?

Comment: The very last closing `}` should actually be `});`

Comment: It removes it's parent <li>, but I got that working thought :)

Comment: It's not my whole JS file hence the syntax mistake while moving into stackoverflow. Thanks fro noticing! @pmahomme

Comment: You are trying to see if it is the first element after you remove it. You should be checking it before you remove it. Might be better to see if there is only no lis after you remove it.

Comment: I don't see why you need to target if it's the first element ... if there is just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to check if the last `<li>` was removed (read: the `<ul>` has no more `<li>`):

```
$('body').on( 'click', 'li > button', function() {
    var list = $(this).closest( 'ul' );

    $(this).parent().remove()

    //* if the UL is empty we can remove it altogether
    if( list ).find( 'li' ).length == 0 ) remove( list ); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it working by dealing with the li and ul instead of the buttons! Why didn't I thought of this before! https://jsfiddle.net/uxt8pv8g/1/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to evaluate if there is more than one element, try this:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'li > button', function() {
   if(($('li > button').length > 1)) {
     $(this).parent().remove();
   } else {
     $(this).parents('ul').remove();
     console.log('Remove other items')
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <button type="button">Remove</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <button type="button">Remove</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When one button is left it should delete the whole list. https://jsfiddle.net/uxt8pv8g/1/ but simpler code thanks @DaniP

Comment: @Heraclitus the code works `parents('ul')` is the same as `parent().parent()` but simpler ... https://jsfiddle.net/uxt8pv8g/2/

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! I thought it was just deleting the li. I got it working after all by workin with the li and ul, thank you!! @DaniP https://jsfiddle.net/uxt8pv8g/1/

Comment: Glad to help U @Heraclitus if it was helpfull don't forget to mark it as answer that solved